# Computer fonts - Small Hane Inkblot Thing

Tags: kanji, history, stroke-count, style, stroke-type

I noticed that some fonts have a small, stylized inkblot on the end of certain strokes in kanji. When I first realized this, I honestly thought that I, myself, was having a stroke! Regardless, I have come to accept that they are there, but I would like to see if anyone knows why it is there or who made the decision to put it there in the first place. I guess it looks kind of cool, but it also shoves (usually the bottom) strokes practically on top of their higher-placed comrades. Your thoughts on them as a whole?

Image added for reference:
[image: Wierd Ink Drip]

Comment: The circled blot in your picture is the main part of a [はね](https://shodo-kanji.com/a3-4-6brush_stroke.html). But I wonder if you are actually asking about serif. Would you also have that "stroke" reaction to a Latin-based serif typeface, say, roman or Times New Roman?

Comment: Serif typefaces for Chinese go back like a thousand years, so you may have difficulty pinpointing a specfic person who introduced this particular flourish, though I'm not sure exactly when it started to appear.

Comment: @EddieKal It is peculiar that you mention that it is serif. At the time of writing, that word had evaded my inner lexicon. What's more, indeed, is that the author of the manga from which my image is composed is Keiichi Arawi, who also created Nichijou, in which a fictional manga exists that is aptly named "Helvetica Standard." The timing of the conception of my serif/hane confusion and my immersion into his works leads me to believe that there is more to this occurring within the collective human subconscious. That is to say: Perhaps Japanese people feel similarly about those English fonts.

Comment: Also, for reference, the font family "Helvetica Standard" lacks a serif, itself. So perhaps there is some sort of universal stealing/borrowing going on here. lol.

Comment: The circled part of that stroke is not a はね. The part outside of that circle is. I don’t know what the circled part is called, but it’s more like an initial とめ.

Comment: @aguijonazo I thought とめ referred to 収筆部分. Is that not correct?

Comment: @EddieKal: Yes, but the position of the brush that would result in the circled part of the stroke is the same as in a とめ. The brush rests there before it goes up for the はね. Like I said, I don’t know what it is called.

Comment: @aguijonazo Ahh I see. Thanks! I found some YouTube clips of Japanese and Chinese calligraphy, and it now makes sense to me! I found a similar term in Chinese: 頓筆 which seems to share the same meaning as とめ

Comment: You can search on youtube 'さんずい　書道' to see why it is there. It is a specific design common in 明朝体. (It is mentioned in [an official document on kanji variation (p5)](https://www.bunka.go.jp/seisaku/bunkashingikai/kokugo/shoiinkai/iinkai_19/pdf/shiryo_6.pdf) )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one of characteristics of [明朝体](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_(typefaces)), the stylized emphases at the start and end of a brush stroke. In calligraphy, you are instructed to sink down your brush firmly at the beginning of every stroke. Then you will see more or less a 45-degree northwest-ward sesami-shaped blot there in each handwritten stroke, which is the ultimate origin of it.

[image]

However, if I had to name someone as the inventor of this highly exaggerated ornament that you see, I'd perhaps suggest an Irish-American called William Gamble, who directed [美華書館](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%BE%8E%E8%8F%AF%E6%9B%B8%E9%A4%A8) (The American Presbyterian Mission Press). He made the first modern moveable type font of Chinese characters in order to print Bible. By analogy to Western serifed typefaces, he introduced many geometrical features and stylization into the 明朝体 design at his time, resulting such a typeface below (see the particular stroke-initial element of 冷) ([source](https://read01.com/2GRNdBK.html)).

[image]

Compare it with the Kangxi dictionary head-character, representing a more standard style for the woodblock printing technology at that time, with humbler stroke-initial tittle more faithful to handwriting practice.

[image]

Although his typeface looks somewhat clunky, it was imported in Japan and served as the earliest prototype of then-cutting-edge metal type technology to set the standard, which is why many Japanese old-style 明朝体 typefaces still inherit this feature.